# Annotations vs. Interface in Guava EventBus

Tags: java, interface, annotations, guava, event-bus

The [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) developers chose to use annotations:

```
class EventBusChangeRecorder {
  @Subscribe 
  void recordCustomerChange(ChangeEvent e) {
    recordChange(e.getChange());
  }
}
```

...  instead of classic interfaces:

```
class EventBusChangeRecorder implements Handler<ChangeEvent>{
  void handle(ChangeEvent e) {
    recordChange(e.getChange());
  }
}
```

This makes compile time checking impossible. So I'm wondering what is the advantage of this approach.

Do you see any advantages of annotations here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that the question is answered on the Guava [wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained#why-use-an-annotation-to-mark-handler-methods-rather-than-requiring-the-listener-to-implement-an-interface).