# Guava EventBus: Subscribe without annotations?

Tags: java, events, guava

I need to implement a pub/sub system within a domain model.  I was thinking about using Guava's EventBus, but I'd like to use interfaces and adapters to keep my domain model ignorant of such an implementation detail.  Unfortunately, EventBus's use of annotations for subscription throw a monkey wrench at this idea.

Is there any way to subscribe a handler without using the @Subscribe annotation?  Looking at the docs, there doesn't seem to be but perhaps there's something I'm not seeing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guava team member here.

It's quite deliberate that you can only subscribe a handler with the `@Subscribe` annotation -- `EventBus` is intended to *replace* interfaces, adapters, etc., not to supplement them -- but why do you say that exposes *more* implementation details?  In our experience, it usually exposes fewer details.

Comment: @OP: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985875/annotations-vs-interface-in-guava-eventbus).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I read the Wiki and agree that use of @Subscribe is A Better Way(tm).  That said, I'm striving to keep my domain model clean and free from implementation and infrastructure details, even persistence annotations and the Subscribe annotation and subscription pattern is unique to Guava.  I wanted to try to hide this from my domain.

Comment: I do not agree, you could get advantage of Java 8's lambdas and have a cleaner code. I wrote an small event bus you can find here: https://github.com/jamming/dojo/tree/master/museum/src/main/java/co/popapp/bus I still have to update it to Java 8 though

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to adapt the Handler. Something like:

```
class GuavaHandler<T extends Message> implements Handler<T> {
    private Handler<T> handler;

    public GuavaHandler(Handler<T> handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    @Subscribe
    public void handle(T message) {
        try {
            handler.getClass().getMethod("handle", message.getClass());
            handler.handle(message);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
            // workaround
        }
    }
}
```

You only define the attribute in this specific implementation.